# Best Android Developer method of payout for a 15 year old?

Tags: android, mobile, credit-card

I am a 15 year old Android developer and I am wondering what the best way to get paid from the Android Market is. Do they have something like mailing checks or the like? I dont have a credit card or anything.

Comment: Don't pay any attention to @Stefan. He must have got up on the wrong side of the bed.

Comment: Thanks Kratz. No worries, I'm just new to the money-making business

Comment: I wish something like the android market had been around when I was 15. Nobody was buying games written in QBasic back then. Hope you do have success!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your 15, I think you're old enough to get a joint savings account at a bank with one of your parents. Then it's a matter of direct deposit, which is fast and easy.

Comment: Would I be old enough for a bank card as well? I am with TD Canada Trust.

Comment: @Qasim, Honestly I'm not sure. I got my first debit card when I started college. Most banks have so called 'Student Checking' accounts with no fees and such. But you wouldn't need a bank card to get paid, only if you wanted make a payment. You can accept payments into a savings account with the banks Routing number and your account number.

Comment: I got my first debit card at 14 - just depends on the bank.

Answer (score 1):

Realistically, the best way is to make your own apps and use ad's through AdMob or some other variant. You won't find an employer that will contract with a 15 year old.

Comment: I think he's talking about payment methods from Android Market place, not getting contracted by an actual software firm.

Comment: Yeah I have Android apps that I am developing right now and just need a method of payout (not sure what its exactly called) to get started. I had a prepaid credit card to pay the 25 bucks but I cant rely on those since mine will expire in a couple of months soon.

Comment: Almost any bank will let you open up a savings account and get a Debit card (which is a Credit card minus the credit).